# How to externalise .properties files when deploying a Spring Boot WAR in Wildfly Server?

Tags: spring, maven, jboss, wildfly, war

I am developing a web application using Spring Boot, and want to generate war instead of jar.
It works fine using the conversion from jar to war described here : http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

But I want to externalize the application.properties from the war, because I want to be able to modify it without opening the war archive.

I already defined the spring-boot-maven plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
                <mainClass>
                  com.application.Application
                </mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I think I need to add `Dependency: config` to my manifest file.
So, I've done it like that :

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Dependencies>config</Dependencies>
                </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

But when I launch the Application.war on Wildfly 8.4, I've got this

```
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.Application.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.screening.war\".main: JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.Application.war:main
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: config:main"}}
```

I would like that my application start with my custom MANIFEST.MF (with Dependency: config) so that I can externalize my application.properties file.

Thank you.

Comment: An external config should be supported without all these changes.

Comment: It works properly when I build the application in serverless mode (jar).
The **application.properties** is in the same directory as **application.jar**, I type `java -jar application.jar` and it works.
But with Wildfly. If I put the **application.war** in `standalone/deployments/` and **application.properties** in `modules/`, the application says that a properties file is missing.

Comment: Can you try with setting `spring.config.location`  property at JVM level(`-D`)? [More](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Comment: @leopal : I know this setting and it works in standalone mode. But I wanted to launch my application without this parameter (to be easier to use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the server side !

When you specify a package, you need to add a **module.xml** file with a Wildfly server.

So in `modules/config/main/`, I've added my **application.properties** and a **module.xml** file that contains :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="config">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="."/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

Thank you for your response @NielsNet.